# Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: wcf-binding, asp.net-core-6.0

I am upgrading a 3.1 .net core web api project to .net core 6. The project has a binding to a WCF service. Before it worked fine with 4.0x version of System.ServiceModel.*. But after upgrade, I am getting the below error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I added `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` to the project as below.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
 <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
 <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But that didn't fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Does the blog useful to you ?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/wcf-client-60-has-been-released/)